# hyperref - pdftex warning (ext4) destination with same identifier

Tags: hyperref, warnings

I am currently working on a document with fixed format, which also includes multiple sections and subsections with the same numbering appearing in it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[usehighlevels]{alnumsec}
\alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}
\surroundarabic[{.}][]{}{}
\otherseparators{1}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}

\usepackage[colorlinks,plainpages]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue}

\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}
\tocless\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{...}
\subsubsection{...}
\subsubsection{...}
\subsection{...}
\subsubsection{...}


\section{Description of the parts}

\section*{Part A}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Part A}
\tocless\subsection{On Part A}
\tocless\subsubsection{all the numbers are fixed}
\tocless\subsubsection{I have no power on the numbering}
\tocless\subsubsection{so this has to be 2.1.3}
\tocless\subsubsection{and this has to be 2.1.4}

\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\section*{Part B}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Part B}
\tocless\subsection{On Part B}
\tocless\subsubsection{all the numbers are fixed}
\tocless\subsubsection{I have no power on the numbering}
\tocless\subsubsection{so this has to be 2.1.3}
\tocless\subsubsection{and this has to be 2.1.4}

\end{document}
```

Sadly, `hyperref` doesn't like it one bit and complains repeatedly about it:

```
(./Proposal.out) (./Proposal.out) (./Proposal.toc) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/t
exmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2pdfTeX warning (ext4): destinat
ion with the same identifier (name{subsection.0.2.1}) has been already used, du
plicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.70 \end{document}
               pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier 
(name{subsubsection.0.2.1.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.70 \end{document}
               pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier 
(name{subsubsection.0.2.1.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.70 \end{document}
               pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier 
(name{subsubsection.0.2.1.3}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.70 \end{document}
               pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier 
(name{subsubsection.0.2.1.4}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.70 \end{document}
               ] (./Proposal.aux) )
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the warning? It appears quite often during compilation in the actual document I am working on, making other warnings far less visible.

From the answers in the other threads there doesn't seem to be a way to manually suppressing that particular warning... :(

Comment: A last resort method: `hypertexnames=false` in `\hypersetup`. The `hyperref` anchors are confused by this!

Comment: A better solution needs details about the reasonings why some parts shouldn't be 'toc'ed.

Comment: How the TOC should look is also fixed by a given template that I must follow, which requires that some subsections and subsubsections do not appear in it.

Comment: If you don't need numbered sections etc. and they should not appear in the ToC as well, then use `\section*{...}` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use `hypertexnames=false` or provide a dummy counter to let `hyperref` make 'correct' anchors, see the `\tocless` command.

I try to provide a better version with another setup!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[usehighlevels]{alnumsec}
\alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}
\surroundarabic[{.}][]{}{}
\otherseparators{1}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}

\usepackage[colorlinks,plainpages]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue}%,hypertexnames=false}

\newcounter{dummycounter}
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\stepcounter{dummycounter}\bgroup\let\theHsection\thedummycounter\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}
\tocless\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{...}
\subsubsection{...}
\subsubsection{...}
\subsection{...}
\subsubsection{...}


\clearpage
\section{Description of the parts}

\section*{Part A}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Part A}
\tocless\subsection{On Part A}
\tocless\subsubsection{all the numbers are fixed}
\tocless\subsubsection{I have no power on the numbering}
\tocless\subsubsection{so this has to be 2.1.3}
\tocless\subsubsection{and this has to be 2.1.4}

\clearpage

\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\section*{Part B}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Part B}
\tocless\subsection{On Part B}
\tocless\subsubsection{all the numbers are fixed}
\tocless\subsubsection{I have no power on the numbering}
\tocless\subsubsection{so this has to be 2.1.3}
\tocless\subsubsection{and this has to be 2.1.4}

\end{document}
```